How can I use a library from Github?
I'd like to use this math library. How can I use it?
I copied the code and created the file /Users/a/forth/exponent.fth but when I tried to include this I get "no such file" error:
include /Users/a/forth/exponent.fth 
/Users/a/forth/exponent.fth:3: No such file or directory
require >>>/Users/a/forth/modulo.fth<<<
Backtrace:
$100C54EF8 throw 
$100C55000 required 

I changed the address of the required file to my local file as well:
require /Users/a/forth/modulo.fth

What do I need to do to use this library? Thanks.
EDIT
It looks like the require is throwing the error:
require math/modulo.fth

I entered the full path in my machine and it seems to work now.
